# Duplicate records with Multiple joins

Tags: sql-server

I had written a join query statement. that statement returns me multiple(duplicate) row again even though I'm having only single record on that.

```
declare @BenefitClass int ;

set @BenefitClass = (select BenefitClass  From HJOB where userid='d76c5000-69e0-461e-92e1-3cfe7590d098' and CompanyId =1629)
select @BenefitClass;
select   
bve.EmployerContribution,  
bhsac.CatchUpValue as CatchUpValue  ,  
bcl.Tier,  
bcl.planYear,  
bhsac.Ischecked,  
isnull(bhsac.Value,0) as EmployeeContribute,  
Id=(convert(varchar, bcl.Id) + '$' + convert(varchar, isnull(bhsac.Id, 0))) ,  
bhsac.Value ,
bhsac.HSALmitId  
from    
dbo.benContributionStructure bcs   
inner join  dbo.benVariableElection bve on bcs.PlanInfoId = bve.PlanInfoId   
inner join dbo.benBenefitContributionLimit bcl on bcs.SavingCategory =       bcl.CategoryID  
left outer join dbo.benBenefitHSACoverage bhsac on bcs.PlanInfoId =   bhsac.planInfoId 
        and bcl.Id=bhsac.HSALmitId --and bhsac.BenefitClassId=@BenefitClass 
        and bhsac.UserID='d76c5000-69e0-461e-92e1-3cfe7590d098' and  bhsac.PlanInfoId=38044
left outer join dbo.benEmployeeContribution bec on bhsac.UserID = bec.UserId    and bhsac.BenefitClassId = bec.BenefitClassId -- and  bec.EnrollmentType !='Closed'
left outer join benOpenEnrollment oems on oems.ID = bec.OpenEnrollmentId and  oems.EndDt > GETDATE()               
where    
bcs.PlanInfoId=38044  and bcl.Ischecked=1   
                       and bcl.Tier !='CatchUp'    
     and bcl.CompanyId=1629
```

For that I'm getting the result as second row as duplicate :

[observe the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfKLq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this once it may help you

```
declare @BenefitClass int ;

set @BenefitClass = (select BenefitClass  From HJOB where userid='d76c5000-69e0-461e-92e1-3cfe7590d098' and CompanyId =1629)
select @BenefitClass;

;with cte as (
select   
bve.EmployerContribution,  
bhsac.CatchUpValue as CatchUpValue  ,  
bcl.Tier,  
bcl.planYear,  
bhsac.Ischecked,  
isnull(bhsac.Value,0) as EmployeeContribute,  
Id=(convert(varchar, bcl.Id) + '$' + convert(varchar, isnull(bhsac.Id, 0))) ,  
bhsac.Value ,
bhsac.HSALmitId  
from    
dbo.benContributionStructure bcs   
inner join  dbo.benVariableElection bve on bcs.PlanInfoId = bve.PlanInfoId   
inner join dbo.benBenefitContributionLimit bcl on bcs.SavingCategory =       bcl.CategoryID  
left outer join dbo.benBenefitHSACoverage bhsac on bcs.PlanInfoId =   bhsac.planInfoId 
        and bcl.Id=bhsac.HSALmitId --and bhsac.BenefitClassId=@BenefitClass 
        and bhsac.UserID='d76c5000-69e0-461e-92e1-3cfe7590d098' and  bhsac.PlanInfoId=38044
left outer join dbo.benEmployeeContribution bec on bhsac.UserID = bec.UserId    and bhsac.BenefitClassId = bec.BenefitClassId -- and  bec.EnrollmentType !='Closed'
left outer join benOpenEnrollment oems on oems.ID = bec.OpenEnrollmentId and  oems.EndDt > GETDATE()               
where    
bcs.PlanInfoId=38044  and bcl.Ischecked=1   
                       and bcl.Tier !='CatchUp'    
     and bcl.CompanyId=1629 
     )
     select distinct EmployerContribution,  
CatchUpValue ,Tier,planYear,Ischecked,EmployeeContribute,Id ,Value ,HSALmitId  from  cte
```

Comment: Can I know why you went with CTE ?

Comment: Nothing great trick..i just used the **Distinct**  for the data that was fetching from CTE.

Comment: Yes, I understood about distinct which gave me exact expected reult. But i was confused with CTE. I'm beginner to sql server. I did the same distinct without fetching from CTE.

Comment: Read the documentation for CTE http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/1343/common-table-expressions#t=201701030610231876676

Answer (score 0):

Please change your where condition as below:

```
select   
bve.EmployerContribution,  
bhsac.CatchUpValue as CatchUpValue  ,  
bcl.Tier,  
bcl.planYear,  
bhsac.Ischecked,  
isnull(bhsac.Value,0) as EmployeeContribute,  
Id=(convert(varchar, bcl.Id) + '$' + convert(varchar, isnull(bhsac.Id, 0))) ,  
bhsac.Value ,
bhsac.HSALmitId  
from    
dbo.benContributionStructure bcs   
inner join  dbo.benVariableElection bve on bcs.PlanInfoId = bve.PlanInfoId   
inner join dbo.benBenefitContributionLimit bcl on bcs.SavingCategory =       bcl.CategoryID  
left outer join dbo.benBenefitHSACoverage bhsac on bcs.PlanInfoId =   bhsac.planInfoId 
        and bcl.Id=bhsac.HSALmitId --and bhsac.BenefitClassId=@BenefitClass 

left outer join dbo.benEmployeeContribution bec on bhsac.UserID = bec.UserId    and bhsac.BenefitClassId = bec.BenefitClassId -- and  bec.EnrollmentType !='Closed'
left outer join benOpenEnrollment oems on oems.ID = bec.OpenEnrollmentId 
where    
bcs.PlanInfoId=38044  and bcl.Ischecked=1   
                       and bcl.Tier !='CatchUp'    
     and bcl.CompanyId=1629 
     and bhsac.UserID='d76c5000-69e0-461e-92e1-3cfe7590d098' 
     and  bhsac.PlanInfoId=38044
    and  oems.EndDt > GETDATE()
```